# How to change input value in formly?

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I want to append "}"(curly braces) to model property_name given by the user .

```
                                   key: 'property_name',
                                   type: 'input',
                                   templateOptions: {
                                       type:'text',
                                       label: 'property name',
                                       required : true
                                   },
```

for example: if user type "star" then "star }" will go to backend.

Comment: Can you please share the script?

Comment: <formly-form model="vm.rental" fields="vm.rentalFields" form="vm.rentalForm">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="vm.fun()">ADD</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.submit(vm.rental)">Submit</button>
    </formly-form>   in vm.rentalField array above mentioned code is an input type and i want the value given by the user in form will have "}" attached when it comes to backend.

Comment: Do you want to show the postfix **}** to the user? If not you can just add the postfix to the **type** field when you save it.

Comment: i want to  add "}" the postfix to the type field when I save it.

Comment: Please give sample input and output

Comment: As its already mentioned in question if user type "star" then on backend it will be like "star }"

Comment: The best way to accomplish this with angular is to use the `$parsers` api. angular-formly doesn't currently support this but it should very soon. https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly/issues/368

Comment: Kent just released a beta version of this functionality, you might want to test it: https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly/issues/368#issuecomment-124573503